# VHDL. The signal value isn't changed after new value assigning

Tags: vhdl

I received a task to describe RAM from my university. I've written a code that should simulate the behaviour of the aforementioned device in my opinion. But it doesn't seem to work.

An entity of the device I've described in the following way:

```vhdl
LIBRARY ieee;
USE ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
USE ieee.std_logic_arith.all;
LIBRARY RAM_lib;
USE RAM_lib.RAM_pkg.all;

ENTITY RAM IS
   GENERIC(
      WORD_LENGTH: INTEGER := 8;
      ADDRESS_LENGTH: integer := 8
    );
   PORT( 
      Enable   : IN     std_logic;
      DATA_IN  : IN     std_logic_vector(WORD_LENGTH - 1  downto 0);
      DATA_OUT : OUT    std_logic_vector(WORD_LENGTH  - 1 downto 0);
      ADDR     : IN     std_logic_vector(ADDRESS_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
      RESET    : IN     std_logic;
      CLK      : IN     std_logic;
      WR       : IN     std_logic;
      RD       : IN     std_logic
   );

-- Declarations

END RAM ;
```

And the behavior part looks like:

```vhdl
use work.RAM_pkg.all;

architecture behavior of ram is

  ---- DATA TYPES DECLARATIONS
  -- used type declarations
  subtype DATA is std_logic_vector(WORD_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
  subtype ADDRESS is std_logic_vector(ADDRESS_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
  type MEMORY is array (0 to 2**ADDRESS_LENGTH - 1) of DATA;

  ---- SIGNAL DECLARATION
  signal RAM : MEMORY;
begin  use work.RAM_pkg.all;

architecture behavior of ram is

  ---- DATA TYPES DECLARATIONS
  -- used type declarations
  subtype DATA is std_logic_vector(WORD_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
  subtype ADDRESS is std_logic_vector(ADDRESS_LENGTH - 1 downto 0);
  type MEMORY is array (0 to 2**ADDRESS_LENGTH - 1) of DATA;

  ---- SIGNAL DECLARATION
  signal RAM : MEMORY;
begin

-- plug in or plug out ram
plug_in_out: process (enable) is  
  variable first_load : boolean := true;
  begin
    if ((enable = '0' and enable'event) or first_load = true) then
      data_out <= (others => 'Z');

      if (first_load = true) then
        first_load := false;
      end if;
    end if;  
  end process;

reset_ram: process (reset) is
    variable initialized: boolean := false;
  begin
    if ((reset = '1' and reset'event) or (initialized = false)) then
      ram <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));

      if (initialized = false) then
        initialized := true;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

 -- it serves both "read" and "write" operation for the RAM
  read_write: process (clk) is
    variable index : integer range 0 to 2**address_length - 1;
  begin
      if (enable = '1' and clk = '1' and clk'event) then
        index := toInt(addr);

        if (wr = '1') then
          ram(index) <= data_in;
        end if;

        if (rd = '1') then
          data_out <= ram(index);
        end if;
      end if;
  end process;
end architecture behavior;



-- plug in or plug out ram
plug_in_out: process (enable) is  
  variable first_load : boolean := true;
  begin
    if ((enable = '0' and enable'event) or first_load = true) then
      data_out <= (others => 'Z');

      if (first_load = true) then
        first_load := false;
      end if;
    end if;  
  end process;

reset_ram: process (reset) is
    variable initialized: boolean := false;
  begin
    if ((reset = '1' and reset'event) or (initialized = false)) then
      ram <= (OTHERS => (OTHERS => '0'));

      if (initialized = false) then
        initialized := true;
      end if;
    end if;
  end process;

 -- it serves both "read" and "write" operation for the RAM
  read_write: process (clk) is
    variable index : integer range 0 to 2**address_length - 1;
  begin
      if (enable = '1' and clk = '1' and clk'event) then
        index := toInt(addr);

        if (wr = '1') then
          ram(index) <= data_in;
        end if;

        if (rd = '1') then
          data_out <= ram(index);
        end if;
      end if;
  end process;
end architecture behavior;
```

[The timing diagram](https://www.dropbox.com/s/5hpsteja5etf964/result.png?dl=1)
[image: The timing diagram]

Thus, the main question is why the initialization hasn't been performed as it has been indicated in 5th line in `reset_ram` process. The debug of the code shows that the aforementioned line is executed but the value of the RAM signal remains unchanged.

Comment: Why are you initializing RAM if the contents aren't valid until written? There is no parity or ECC present,  The 'U's or resulting 'X's tell you if you read a memory location not previously written, and unlike your waveform dump the entire contents are not available concurrently to your enclosing design.

Comment: Could you explain in details that you mean by "Why are you initializing RAM if the contents aren't valid until written". But I'm no sure that I've clearly understood you. Did you mean that a write operation could appear earlier that RAM was initialized?

Answer (score 2):

In VHDL, a signal should be assigned in a single process. Otherwise, you will get multiple-drivers, which are generally not synthesizable. Also assigning multiple values to the same signal in simulation will lead to conflict if the driven values are incompatible (such as driving both '0' and '1', which would yield 'X').

Scanning through your code, I can see that at least `data_out` and `ram` have assignments in multiple processes. Merging your processes should solve your problem.

Furthermore, a RAM can't be reset. This is not relevant for simulation, but will affect synthesis. You can reset the output registers (`data_out`), but the RAM itself can't have a reset. If you do, the synthesizer will use registers instead of embedded RAM. However, you can have initial content for the RAM, by defining it like this `signal ram: MEMORY := (others => (others => '0'));`. This is supported by synthesis.

Comment: Thanks David, made the change

Answer (score 1):

There are several problems here. First, as has been mentioned, you should never write to the same signal with multiple processes, or you have multiple driver problems.

If you really want an asynchronous enable (closest to what you describe in `plug_in_out`), then you need a separate signal for the real output. for example:

```
data_out_real <= (others => 'Z') when enable = '0' else data_out;
```

which is a single line of combinational VHDL (not inside a process). Nevertheless, I don't reccommend an async enable, you'd do perfectly fine with a synchronous enable operating in your main process.

The variable manipulation you use to get an initial state probably won't synthesize either, but you don't need one. data_out_real will always have a value either explicit (`"ZZZZ..."`) or a copy of data_out. You can give data_out an give an initial value when you declare the signal with:

```
signal data_out : std_logic_vector(word_length-1 downto 0) := (others => '0');
```

Assuming you are trying to create a ram module targeting an FPGA, you can't reset everything at once (you can in a register file, but a RAM is different) as you try to do in the `reset_ram` process (it will simulate, and maybe synthesize, but not into the FPGA's block RAM). The normal way to do this is to trigger a reset state when reset goes high that has a counter that iterates through every address assigning one location to 0 every clock. Note that this state machine occupies the same process as your normal read/write behaviour (which is in the non-reset state). Note also that this won't be an asynchronous reset like you sort-of described in `reset_ram`.

The actual `read_write` process looks alright for the read/write state of your ram, although you don't need the index variable/assignment, it is just as easy to do the conversion in your 2 ram indexing operations with fewer lines.

To implement an enable here you may want to separate the `enable='1'` and `clk='1' and clk'event` into separate if layers. This allows you to put a default value of 0 or even Z's for your data out (must be inside of your clk rising edge check, outside of/in the else section of your enable check). If you actually wanted a synchronous enable then it is better to do something like that instead of the combinational bit that I demoed above. Furthermore, if you *did* want/have an async enable, you would need to deal with cross clock paths to use it in your synchronous process here.

Lastly, think about what you really want your enable to do. In most RAMs that I've described, I don't want to lose the last read value when enable goes low, I just don't want it to change. This is even easier to accomplish, as you can just not mention what to do when enable is low, and the signal will keep its last value.